# Do cookies track current tab or information from all tabs?

Tags: security, cookies, web, web-applications

Do cookies track current tab or information from all tabs?

The reason I'm asking is because if it's the former, then that means it's safer to open web apps like online code editors or mail etc. in a new tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are automatically installed in your browser and it will not fixed to a particular tab .It grabs information from all tabs .

> if you want to escape from cookies you need to browse in incognito window in google chrome or in private window in Firefox.

This browsing is very safe from cookies.